# iOS IBM Bluemix Push Notifications Server Pretending

Tags: ios, push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I am using IBM Bluemix for push notification services. I was able to send myself multiple notifications a few hours ago. I added GCM information to the Push config in my Bluemix app. Another developer used my computer to create a new Bluemix app to try and replicate my app for understanding. They used the same .p12 file I used for my app and now when I run my iOS app connected to my Bluemix app or their Bluemix app I get this error:

```
2015-08-18 15:56:55.377 IBMBluemixNotifications[721:75912] INFO: Checking for 

previous registration of this application.
2015-08-18 15:56:55.378 IBMBluemixNotifications[721:75912] INFO: Using the identifierForVendor API for UUID.
2015-08-18 15:56:55.382 IBMBluemixNotifications[721:75912] INFO: Payload :: (null)
2015-08-18 15:56:55.383 IBMBluemixNotifications[721:75912] INFO: URL :: https://mnppushnotifications.mybluemix.net/push/v1/apps/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/devices?filter=registrationId%20==%206CBD6BD1-135D-49FC-A9D1-031D6714ECE4&expand=true
2015-08-18 15:56:56.692 IBMBluemixNotifications[721:75977] NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843)
2015-08-18 15:56:56.696 IBMBluemixNotifications[721:75912] ERROR: Request failure: url=https://mnppushnotifications.mybluemix.net/push/v1/apps/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/devices?filter=registrationId%20==%206CBD6BD1-135D-49FC-A9D1-031D6714ECE4&expand=true NSURLERRORDOMAIN--1202E: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “mnppushnotifications.mybluemix.net” which could put your confidential information at risk.
```

I deleted the other developer's app on Bluemix but I am still getting the same error. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you testing the application on the same device? What iOS version are you testing against (iOS 8, iOS 9, etc). Also you talk in your post about GCM information, but then start speaking of iOS. Are you testing on both iOS and Android? Also did you edit the URL in the above requests to hide the app id?

Comment: @Jaalger Yes same device. iOS 8. For the GCM I was trying to test with an Android device so I added GCM credentials but was unable test on Android device (couldn't get one), that is when the other dev started to replicate the project back to iOS. Yes I hid my app id.

Comment: I looked into this issue on some other forums. It seems if your date and time gets out of sync on the device it can cause similar error messages:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4912924
Can you attempt to see if maybe that is the cause of this issue. Also another technote here from apple to look into:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2232/_index.html

Comment: It wasn't the date object it was the .p12 conflicts, issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

When the other developer tried to replicate my app on Bluemix they uploaded the same .p12 file I used in my Bluemix app. When both certs are uploaded and running, Bluemix flags your apps to have duplicate cert error. If you delete only one of the app the flag is not removed therefor I had to delete my Bluemix app and start over, reloaded the same cert to Bluemix and only one app and then it started to work.

Comment: It won't let me till tomorrow

Comment: Now it won't work even after deleting the app on Bluemix and re uploading my cert. Any ideas?

Comment: Could my cert have been flagged on Bluemix servers as a bad cert and not usable anymore?